# OneSignal | Get URL from notification payload and open in custom WebView

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-webview

OneSignal provides functionality to open URLs in a browser by default. I want to send a URL with notifications that open the URL in a `WebView` that I have created. I've shared a snipper of where I receive the notification:

```
 class ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
      @Override
      public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
        JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
        String customKey;

        if (data != null) {
          customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
          if (customKey != null)
            Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to retrieve the URL on the push being opened and open it in the `WebView`.

Comment: Are you setting the custom URL through the OneSignal dashboard?

Comment: targetURL in Include Additional Data? available in the dashboard

Comment: OneSignal doesn't handle additional data itself. It is called 'additional' because it is for you to handle as you may. Posting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer from SlashG, helped me. Here is my implementation... I added this code in my Application class `onCreate()`

```
OneSignal.startInit(this).setNotificationOpenedHandler(new OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {

                String launchURL = result.notification.payload.launchURL;

                if (launchURL != null) {
                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Launch URL: " + launchURL);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.putExtra("url", launchURL);
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Launch URL not found");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }).init();
```

Comment: Hi @Vamsi Chalia, can you please tell me where did you put this code? In which file in your app?

Comment: I added the code in Application class on create method

Comment: Tnx I have found it.

Comment: But i have problems, can you help me a little bit? I have just copied it, of course it doesn't work. What do i need to change? https://s21.postimg.org/48p3y9xtz/image.png

Comment: The OSNotificationOpenResult is part of OneSignal class. See if you can import OneSignal.OSNotificationOpenResult

Comment: I have these imports on top: import android.os.Build;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144640/discussion-between-lewis4u-and-vamsi-challa).

Answer (score 2):

If you're including the URL in your **Additional Data**, OneSignal will not do anything to use it. Additional Data is for you to use as you may like to. You need to implement a `OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler` and set it to your OneSignal instance when you call `OneSignal.startInit(context)`.

This interface has a callback for when your notification is opened, `notificationOpened()`. This method has an argument of type `OSNotificationOpenResult`. You can retrieve the `notification` > `payload` > `additionalData`. Get your `launch_url` from `additionalData` here and call a `WebView` with it.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Setting up in launch url will open the url in browser not in webview. SlashG, so we need to set target url to as additional data and call it in our app to handle the notification handler but there I don't know how to handle it exactly.

Comment: My bad, I missed the `WebView` part. Updated my answer. This should help. Also, note that I'm using OneSignal SDK 3.3.0. If you have a different version, the implementation might be slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for your support and answer, but what problem is that I could in find examples for it, so it become more difficult for me to implement in my code. I don't know here to put the code so that i might work, So any working examples is appreciated.

Comment: I recommend trying yourself and figuring out. I can share examples, but it is best that you figure it out yourself. It would help you learn. Nonetheless, you plan to open your `Activity` when this notification is opened, right?

Comment: We are so good at android development, we made it work but not the url open in webview as onesignal documentation seems to be so difficult to catch up with that's why asked you a working examples.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: Thats why said you, need some examples

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126581/discussion-between-slashg-and-balaji-jb).

Comment: @SlashG I also need little help just to open the link inside my app....now it opens the smartphone default browser. I can't find any example. If you could please help me.

Comment: @lewis4u how are you opening the URL? If you want a link to open inside your app, you need to create an `Activity` that does so, with a `WebView`. I have created, for one of my projects, a class called `WebViewActivity`. I pass the URL as an extra with the Intent, and use it to show the webpage in a `WebView` in this Activity's layout.